# Clojure and JavaFX 2 -- passing multiple-arity arguments to JavaFX methods

Tags: java, clojure, javafx-2, variadic-functions, clojure-java-interop

A lot of JavaFx methods take var args, such as Group, which is declared in Java as:

```
public Group(Node... children)
```

Others for example:

```
public KeyFrame(Duration time, KeyValue... values)
```

I've discovered the `...` means I should pass a java array to the method, so I've been doing stuff like this,

```
(-> timeline .getKeyFrames 
  (.addAll 
    (into-array [(KeyFrame. blabla) (KeyFrame. blabla)]))`
```

It's annoying to have to do `(into-array...)` every time there is a var arg, and it's more annoying when the var arg is a base class of what I'm actually passing in.  For example

```
(Group. (into-array [(Circle. 100) (Rectangle. 100 100)]))
```

results in type mismatch error.  Instead I have to do this:

```
(Group. (into-array Node [(Circle. 100) (Rectangle. 100 100)]))
```

So i made this function:

```
(defn make-group [& items]
  (Group. (into-array Node items)))
```

which is fine for Groups, but doesn't solve the general problem.

So is there a nice way of solving the ellipses/vararg problem so I don't have to make special functions for each vararg method?  The requirements for this function would be that it take the method you want to call (eg `Group`), the fixed args, the var args, and somehow magically the function would know to find the common base class of the elements in the var args.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the arguments in a vector? I haven't tried all the use cases you mention, but when using the addAll() method for example I just put the arguments into a literal vector, e.g.

```
    (.addAll (.getChildren btn-pane) [new-puzzle-pane check-box hint-btn
                                  check-btn solve-btn load-btn save-btn
                                  print-btn about-btn spacer])
```

Comment: passing vectors directly was what I tried first and got `Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector`

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using a macro, which I kind of suspected I needed:

```
(defmacro jvar [method & args]
  (let [lastargs (last args)
        evaled-lastargs (eval lastargs)]
    (if (coll? evaled-lastargs)
      (let [firstargs (butlast args)
            klass (eval (last firstargs))
            supset (map #(supers (class %)) evaled-lastargs)
            common (apply intersection #{klass} supset)]
        (if (seq common)
          `(~method ~@(butlast firstargs) (into-array ~(first common) ~lastargs))
          `(~method ~@firstargs (into-array ~lastargs)))))))
```

Usage like this:

`(jvar Group. Node [(Circle. 100) (Rectangle. 10 10)])`